# Proof in Kummer Theory - why is this subgroup finite?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm doing a course on elliptic curves. We're working with a field $K$ with $\mu_n \subset K$ ($K$ contains all $n$th roots of unity) and $\mbox{char}(K)\not|\;n$.

I'm trying to understand the proof of

> There is a bijection
>   $$\begin{Bmatrix}\mbox{finite subgroups of }\Delta \subset \frac{K^\times}{(K^\times)^n}\end{Bmatrix}$$
>   $$\leftrightarrow$$ $$ \begin{Bmatrix}\mbox{finite abelian extensions }L/K\mbox{ of exponent dividing }n\end{Bmatrix}$$
>   given by $$\begin{array}{rll} \Delta & \mapsto & L=K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta} \\ \\ \frac{K^\times \cap (L^\times)^n}{(K^\times)^n} & \leftarrow & L. \end{array}$$

Given $\Delta \subset \frac{K^\times}{(K^\times)^n}$, we define $L=K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta})$ and $$\Delta'=\frac{K^\times \cap (L^\times)^n}{(K^\times)^n}$$ We want to show that $\Delta=\Delta'$. Clearly $\Delta \subset \Delta'$. Then we have $$L=K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta})\subset K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta'})\subset L,$$ so these inclusions are equalities. Then the lecturer writes

> by Lemma 10.1, $|\Delta|=|\Delta'|$.

Where Lemma 10.1 says

> Let $\Delta \subset \frac{K^\times}{(K^\times)^n}$ be a finite subgroup. Let $L=K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta})$. 
>   Then $L/K$ is Galois with $$\mbox{Gal}(L/K) \cong \mbox{Hom}(\Delta, \mu_n).$$

But I don't see why we immediately know that $\Delta'$ is finite, which I think we need to know to apply the lemma.

Why are there only finitely many

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i\sqrt[n]{x_i}\right)^n\in K \hspace{10mm} a_i \in K, x_i \in \Delta$$

up to being in the same $(K^\times)^n$ coset?

Comment: What book are you taking the above from?

Comment: And where is elliptic curve? Are you talking about the relations between divisoin points on ellitpic curves and Kummer extensions? In any case, maybe you could make it explicit? Thanks.

Comment: I think the whole group $K^\times/K^{\times n}$ is finite, and hence the subgroups are all finite, at least in the case of local fields. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also notice that your last sentence is not what you have to show; instead, you have to show that $(L^\times)^n\cap K^\times/(K^\times)^n$ is finite. The two notions are different.

Comment: @DonAntonio This stuff is taken from my course on elliptic curves. There are lecture notes at http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/eb525/ec-notes.pdf. My question comes from Proposition 16.2 from the February 22 lecture.

Comment: @awllower You're right - I was assuming the $\sqrt[n]{x_i}$ give us a basis for $L$, which is false. There's no elliptic curve explicitly, but we're doing this stuff in preparation for proving weak Mordel Weil. I don't think local fields are the only fields we care about: the theorem is stated for general $K$ containing the $n$th roots of unity with characteristic not dividing $n$.

Comment: @awllower: $K^\times/K^{\times n}$ is often infinite. For example, let $K$ be the rationals, and $n=2$. Then $K^\times/K^{\times n}$ is infinite. As coset representatives we can use all the square-free integers and their negatives. You are correct to claim that this is quotient is finite, when we have a local field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for pointing out this. I was thinking about traditional theory when I wrote that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if $\Delta \subseteq \frac{K^\times}{(K^\times)^n}$ is not finite, we still get injective homomorphisms $$\operatorname{Gal}(L|K) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\Delta, \mu_n),\quad \Delta \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Gal}(L|K),\mu_n)$$
from the Kummer pairing (look at the proof of Lemma 10.1 again; we didn't use the finiteness until the very end when comparing the orders of the groups). In particular, from the second injective map we get that $\Delta$ is finite if $K(\sqrt[n]{\Delta})|K$ is finite.